# JS Function invokes itself without being called

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have this menu project I made for a company that I work for and it works fine, but I noticed this one quirk that I cannot explain and after days and days of searching I cannot find anything like it on the web.

This is a Vue project that takes in some data from a DB and sorts it to display on a menu. I don't think I can paste the code in its entirety but I will paste the function in question and describe its position in the project as accurately as I can.

So the function I'm speaking of resides inside of another function "sortMenuItems()" that is called on creation of the the Vue page. The "sortMenuItems()" function is defined in methods of the Vue file "Fview.vue", which is a component of "Menu.vue".

Below is the function in question, which resides inside "sortMenuItems()".

```
let intervalCounter = setInterval(() => {
     counter();
     this.flowerArr = randomNarray(menuItems, 16);
}, 27000);
```

As you can see, it is just a simple function expression used to contain an interval counter that periodically calls a function and redefines a variable necessary for the menu to change every 27 seconds. I know setInterval gets a bad rap and we are not supposed to use it, but it works for me here and I'm not pretending to be a pro at this. That being said, for some reason this function invokes itself. I used to call it, but it caused problems because it was already running. Now it is not called anywhere in in the entire project, yet it still runs when sortMenuItems() is called. I've done so much trying to figure out why this is and it bothers me that I don't know why. It obviously doesn't fit the constraints of an IIFE. The project works as it is and I could just probably make this a function declaration or something to write this code in a way that it is intended to behave, but honestly I've kept it around so that I would seek clarification on this. So here I am with my first post every on Stack Overflow. I throw myself to the mercy of code gods in hope of some sort of light on this.

Project dependencies:

- axios
- concurrently (for my jerryrigged cors workaround that involves a separate js sever)
- core-js
- vue
- vuetify

Comment: The code you  posted is, on the whole, **not** a  "function".  It's a variable declaration, wherein the variable "intervalCounter" is assigned the identifier returned from a call to `setInterval()`.  It's not clear where the code appears, but if that `let` declaration happens the interval timer will be started, and a new timer will be started each time that code runs.

Comment: You'r right, I dont know why i called it function expression. Maybe syntactic similarity? Just to clarify, are you saying that since the setInterval() is stored in a variable it runs when the variable is declared?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That declaration **starts** the interval timer. The value stored in "intervalCounter" is useful should your code ever want to stop it with `clearInterval()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! One other question, is this the case for any function declared in a variable? or is intervalCounter a special case or class of cases?

Comment: Well what you've got there is a simple function call expression — the call to the `setInterval()` function. A function definition expression is also involved, the `=>` function passed as a *parameter* to `setInterval()`. The value of the declared variable will be the result of fully evaluating the whole expression, and so that's going to involve calling `setInterval()` to get its return value (the timer identifier).

Comment: I'm going to be doing some reading up on that. Again thank you so much for all the help. I'm trying to figure out how to mark this question solved by you and whatever the equivalent of kudos are here. U definitely deserve the credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) so aptly pointed out, The Function I inquired about is indeed **NOT** a function expression and is actually a variable declaration. In this case it is a function call expression and as pointy put it so succinctly: "The value of the declared variable will be the result of fully evaluating the whole expression". Thus declaring the variable with setInterval() as the value caused it to run.

Hopefully my explanation will be adequate for future readers.

Much thanks to Pointy!!!